# Retrieving dataset values from a particular column into a string

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

In my application, I want to get the data in particular column in dataset and convert it to a string with comma seperation. I've used the code below. But I think it makes the application very slow.

```
string ids = "";
if (datatable1.Rows.Count > 0)         
{
       foreach (DataRow dr in datatable1.Rows)
       {
           ids += dr["id"].ToString() + " ,";
       }

}
```

Can anyone provide some suggestion to improve the code.

Comment: Why do you think it makes your application slow? Also, please note that you can remove the `if (datatable1.Rows.Count > 0)` check, as it's not necessary (your foreach loop will not be entered if there are no rows!)

Comment: How many Rows are there? StringBuilder may be better?

Comment: @DaveHogan: May be in thousands

Comment: An ID is normally numerical, why do you use a string and not a `List<int>`?

Comment: Yes but i want to use it in sql like delete * from table where id in (@ids).

Answer (score 3):

Use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you are doing too many concatenation.

```
StringBuilder ids = new StringBuilder();
if (datatable1.Rows.Count > 0)         
{
       foreach (DataRow dr in datatable1.Rows)
       {
           ids.Append(dr["id"].ToString() + ",");
       }

}
```

Or you may shorten it using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx)

```
string ids = string.Join(",",datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                                       .Select(r=> r.Field<int>("ID")));
```

Comment: Which will be most faster: using foreach or string.join?

Comment: @Vijay, Time both of them, use [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Comment: @Vijay: Both use loops, you should aks (yourself) what is more readable or maintainable.

Comment: @Vijay, thanks for pointing that out. It seems to be fixed now